# Package inputenc Error U+2217 but I don't have an asterisk anywhere

Tags: biblatex, input-encodings

I am using BibLaTex, and in my code I use \printbibliography.
It doesn't compile and gives me the error:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ∗ (U+2217)(inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

This should stand for an asterisk according to [this site](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2217). I do not have an asterisk in any of my files, I thoroughly checked.

I also tried it with an empty .bib file, which gave me the exact same error. I cannot make any sense of the error message.
What am I missing here?

My file compiles without errors, when removing the \printbibliography.

here is my .bib file's content:

```
@article{deepae,
    author = {Zvezdan Lončarević and Rok Pahič and Mihael Simonič and Aleš Ude and Andrej Gams},
    title = {Reduction of Trajectory Encoding Data Using a Deep Autoencoder Network: Robotic Throwing},
    journaltitle = {Advances in Service and Industrial Robotics},
    year = {2019},
}

@article{cong,
    author = {Iris Cong and Soonwon Choi and Mikhail D. Lukin},
    title = {Quantum convolutional neural networks},
    journaltitle = {Nat. Phys. 15, 1273–1278},
    year = {2019},
}



@book{goodfellow,
    title={Deep Learning},
    author={Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville},
    publisher={MIT Press},
    note={\url{http://www.deeplearningbook.org}},
    year={2016},
}

@article{schuld,
    author = {Maria Schuld and Ryan Sweke and Johannes Jakob Meyer},
    title = {The effect of data encoding on the expressive power of variational quantum machine learning models},
    publisher = {American Physical Society},
    journaltitle = {Physical Review A 103, 032430},
    year = {2021},
}

@article{kandala,
    author = {Abhinav Kandala and Antonio Mezzacapo and Kristan Temme and Maika Takita and Markus Brink and Jerry M. Chow and Jay M. Gambetta},
    title = {Hardware-efficient Variational Quantum Eigensolver for Small Molecules and Quantum Magnets},
    journaltitle = {Nature 549, 242–246},
    note = {\url{https://doi.org/10.1038/nature23879}},
    year = {2017},
}

@article{kramer,
    author = {Mark A. Kramer},
    title = {Nonlinear Principal Component Analysis Using Autoassociative Neural Networks},
    journaltitle = {AIChE Journal - Volume 37, Issue 2},
    year = {1991},
}

%@article{mnih,
    author = {Volodymyr Mnih and Koray Kavukcuoglu and David Silver and Daan Wierstra and Alex Graves and Ioannis Antonoglou and Martin Riedmiller},
    title = {Playing Atari with Deep Reinforcement Learning},
    journaltitle = {NIPS Deep Learning Workshop 2013},
    note = {\url{https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5602}},
    year = {2013},
}


@article{mnih2,
    author = {Volodymyr Mnih and Koray Kavukcuoglu and David Silver and Andrei A. Rusu and Joel Veness and Marc G. Bellemare and Alex Graves and Martin Riedmiller and Andreas K. Fidjeland and Georg Ostrovski and Stig Petersen and Charles Beattie and Amir Sadik and Ioannis Antonoglou and Helen King and Dharshan Kumaran and Daan Wierstra and Shane Legg and Demis Hassabis},
    title = {Human-level control through deep reinforcement learning},
    journaltitle = {Nature},
    note={\url{https://doi.org/10.1038/nature14236}},
    year = {2015},
}


@article{jerbi,
    author = {Soene Jerbi and Casper Gyurik and Simon Marshall and Hans J. Briegel and Vedran Dunjko},
    title = {Variational quantum policies for reinforcement learning},
    note={\url{https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.05577}},
    year = {2021},
}

@article{skolik,
    author = {Andrea Skolik and Sofiene Jerbi and Vedran Dunjko},
    title = {Quantum agents in the Gym: a variational quantum algorithm for deep Q-learning},
    note={\url{https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.15084}},
    year = {2021},
}

@article{chen,
    author = {Samuel Yen-Chi Chen and Chao-Han Huck Yang and Jun Qi and Pin-Yu Chen and Xiaoli Ma and Hsi-Sheng Goan},
    title = {Variational Quantum Circuits for Deep Reinforcement Learning},
    journaltitle = {IEEE Access, vol. 8, pp. 141007-141024},
    year = {2020},
}

@article{lockwood,
    author = {Owen Lockwood and Mei Si},
    title = {Reinforcement Learning with Quantum Variational Circuits},
    journaltitle = {DeepAi},
    year = {2020},
}

@article{shor,
    author = {Peter W. Shor},
    title = {Polynomial-Time Algorithms for Prime Factorization and Discrete Logarithms on a Quantum Computer},
    note={\url{https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9508027}},
    year = {1996},
}


@article{grover,
    author = {Lov K. Grover},
    title = {A fast quantum mechanical algorithm for database search},
    journaltitle = {STOC '96: Proceedings of the twenty-eighth annual ACM symposium on Theory of Computing},
    note={\url{https://doi.org/10.1145/237814.237866}},
    year = {1996},
}
```

Comment: Add `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2217}{HEREHEREHERE!!!!}` to your document. Then you should be able to find it.

Comment: Note that the asterisk operator U+2217 (`∗`) is not the same as the usual asterisk U+002A (`*`), this may fool the search function of your editor. You can do `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2217}{XXX - hello here I am ???}` to make your document compile and then you can search for `???` in the output to find where the character is used.

Comment: thank you, that did remove the Error message, but the 'HEREHEREHERE!!!!' doesn't appear anywhere in my document.. what does that mean?

Comment: The entries shown in the question are fine wrt to asterisks, they will not produce the error. But you should look into making the entries more BibTeX/`biblatex`-y: URLs belong into the `url` field (without `\url{...}` wrapper) and not the `note` field. The `journaltitle` field should only hold the title of the journal. Volume, issue number and page ranges should go into the `volume`, `number` and `pages` fields, respectively.

Comment: As for the replacement text in `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` not appearing, this is a bit unexpected. As far as I understand, characters that are not set up for use in LaTeX should only produce an error when they are actually used (about to be printed). It is not enough to have them in the file and not print them (you can for example have `abstract = {∗},` without error if you don't print the abstract). So we would really expect the replacement text to turn up somewhere in the output.